# How to read memory from disk to RAM in assembly bootloader operating in x86 Intel Architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, detection, bootloader, bios

This is not a question about BIOS interrupt int 0x13 ah 0x02 (= Read sectors from drive) service.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H

The point of this question is

Q1. Is there a method to read memory from disk to RAM without using BIOS interrupt (based on legacy boot process, which is not UEFI)?

Q2. How to read memory from disk to RAM without using BIOS interrupt?

If there is a method, explanation in a a step by step fashion will be greatly appreciated.

The purpose of this question is

- Many articles assert that BIOS is so obsolete and unreliable so I'd like to avoid from using it.
- If there is a method, it will be utilized in the first boot sector, which is 0x7C00.

Comment: It's not really possible because the BIOS disk interface abstracts away from the actual disk controller used.  Disk `80h` can very well be a SCSI controller with a custom option ROM and there isn't really a way to find out what the boot disk corresponds to without asking the BIOS.  And even if you were to find out, you needed to write a driver for that device.  Good luck doing all of this in less than 512 bytes!

Comment: On systems that support legacy BIOS, you should at least consider that disk BIOS is stable enough or there would be a great deal of broken bootloader software out there. Legacy BIOS is being phased out, but disk BIOS interrupts running in real mode i(on systems that support legacy boot) s actually preferred especially given you are running this from the boot sector according to the question. However if  your hardware supports it you could look at something basic like using ATA PIO mode directly: https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode .

Comment: Once you move into protected mode you have two options (switch back and forth to real mode to make BIOS calls, but that won't work on systems without legacy BIOS and is usually not the preferred method) or to write drivers to interface with the hardware directly. Then it is a matter of writing drivers to conform to the devices you are communicating with.

Comment: If you are developing for a system that uses bios,  I don't think you should punish yourself by not using interrupts. The bios is not obsolete at all.